# How do I use three parameter constructor in Radiohead library without errors?

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino, arduino-esp32, lora

These are instances declaration mentioned in the examples I opened

```
RH_RF95 rf95;
RH_RF95 rf95(5, 2);
RH_RF95 rf95(8, 3);
```

Opening the RH_RF95.h  header file I saw the following prototype

```
RH_RF95(uint8_t slaveSelectPin = SS, uint8_t interruptPin = 2, 
RHGenericSPI& spi = hardware_spi);
```

Meaning I can also initialize with three argument but if I do it like this

```
RH_RF95 rf95(slaveSelectPin, interruptPin, hspi);
```

I get error that there is no matching function call.

```
radiohead_ex:12:48: error: no matching function for call to 
'RH_RF95::RH_RF95(int&, int&, SPIClass*&)' RH_RF95 rf95(slaveSelectPin, 
    interruptPin, hspi);
```

Why is that?
I really need use the three parameter constructor so I could pass an SPI instance.
[Screenshoot of my code with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f3Wn.png)

Comment: Does the arguments type match the parameter types?

Comment: Please show a [mre] the full compiler error message would help too

Comment: From your screenshot `hspi` appears to be a pointer so needs to be dereferenced before passing to the constructor?